# Making a copy of tkinter.font.Font object without changing its family

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

How do I make a copy of a `tkinter.font.Font` object without changing it's `family` option?

Below is the script I had used and it's output. I was surprised to discover that it's `.copy` method changed the font's family.

**Test Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self._defaultFont=tkFont.Font(family='Times',size='11',weight='normal')        

        self.setFont()


    def setFont(self):
        """Customise Font styles""" 
        Font = self._defaultFont.copy()
        FontBold = self._defaultFont.copy()
        FontBold.config(weight='bold')
        print('_defaultFont.configure = ', self._defaultFont.configure())
        print('Font.configure         = ', Font.configure())
        print('Font.actual            = ', Font.actual())
        print('FontBold.configure     = ', FontBold.configure())
        print('FontBold.actual        = ', FontBold.actual())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    root.geometry('200x100')
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
_defaultFont.configure =  {'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'family': 'Times', 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.configure         =  {'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.actual            =  {'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal'}
FontBold.configure     =  {'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'weight': 'bold'}
FontBold.actual        =  {'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'weight': 'bold'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue described in my question occurred when I had used an invalid font family, i.e. a font that does not exist in `tkinter.font.families()`, to create a `tkinter.font.Font()` object. So there is a need to ensure that a `tkinter.font.families()` font is used with the `.copy()` method.

To demonstrate this, I had investigated the outcome from using fonts such as  `'Times'` and `'Helvetica'`, which does not reside in my Ubuntu 16.04.3 system, and from using fonts such as `'Ubuntu'` and `'URW Gothic L'`, which resides in my system. The output from my investigations are shown below. They show that the `.copy()` method of class `tkinter.font.Font` will exactly duplicate the font's attributes only if the font used are reported by `tkinter.font.families()`. The revised script that I had used to investigate my issue is provided below.

**If a font in tkFont.families() is not used:**

```
_defaultFont.configure =  {'family': 'Times', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
_defaultFont.actual    =  {'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.configure         =  {'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.actual            =  {'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
FontBold.configure     =  {'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'bold'}
FontBold.actual        =  {'family': 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'size': 11, 'underline': 0, 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'bold'}

_defaultFont.configure =  {'family': 'Helvetica', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
_defaultFont.actual    =  {'family': 'Nimbus Sans L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
Font.configure         =  {'family': 'Nimbus Sans L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
Font.actual            =  {'family': 'Nimbus Sans L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
FontBold.configure     =  {'family': 'Nimbus Sans L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'bold', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
FontBold.actual        =  {'family': 'Nimbus Sans L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'weight': 'bold', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0}
```

**If a font in tkFont.families() is used:**

```
Ubuntu in tkFont.families()
_defaultFont.configure =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}
_defaultFont.actual    =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}
Font.configure         =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}
Font.actual            =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}
FontBold.configure     =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'bold', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}
FontBold.actual        =  {'family': 'Ubuntu', 'weight': 'bold', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0}

URW Gothic L in tkFont.families()
_defaultFont.configure =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
_defaultFont.actual    =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.configure         =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
Font.actual            =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'normal'}
FontBold.configure     =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'bold'}
FontBold.actual        =  {'slant': 'roman', 'family': 'URW Gothic L', 'underline': 0, 'size': 11, 'overstrike': 0, 'weight': 'bold'}
```

**Revised Test Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        fontFamilies = tkFont.families()
        print('tkFont.families() = ', fontFamilies)

        testfont = 'URW Gothic L' #change string to the font you want to use
        for font in fontFamilies:
            if testfont == font:
                print('\n{} in tkFont.families()'.format(testfont))
                break

        self._defaultFont=tkFont.Font(family=testfont, size='11',
                                      weight='normal')        
        self.setFont()


    def setFont(self):
        """Customise Font styles""" 
    self.Font = self._defaultFont.copy()
    self.FontBold = self._defaultFont.copy()
    self.FontBold.config(weight='bold')
    print('\n_defaultFont.configure = ', self._defaultFont.configure())
    print('_defaultFont.actual    = ', self._defaultFont.actual())
    print('Font.configure         = ', self.Font.configure())
    print('Font.actual            = ', self.Font.actual())
    print('FontBold.configure     = ', self.FontBold.configure())
    print('FontBold.actual        = ', self.FontBold.actual())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    root.geometry('200x100')
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or are you adding more information to your question?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have amended my answer. Hope it can pass as an answer and can help others faced with similar issue.